# Как на GitHub'е получить точное совпадение в поиске со строкой, которую я ищу?

Tags: git, github, поисковые-системы

Смотрю видео-уроки по программированию. Для того, чтобы не набирать код вручную ищу готовые репозитории на GitHub. Проблема в том, что если приложения создаётся несколько уроков, то найти нужный репозиторий достаточно сложно, постоянно попадаются более ранние версии.
Пробовал искать по строкам, которые присутствуют в коде на видео, но проблема в том, что GitHub не ищет всю строку в точности, а находит результаты с такими же ключевыми словами.
Что мне сделать, чтобы получать точные результаты поиска?
К примеру, я вбиваю строку:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("response");
```

И мне нужно, чтобы поиск выдавал только те фрагменты кода, где есть вся эта строка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433561) на аналогичный вопрос на stackoverflow.com.

Если коротко, то никак. Как обходной путь, предлагают искать по сайту с помощью google. В поисковой строке ввести следующее:

```
"строка_для_поиска" site::https://github.com
```